# os.Create and os.Open not working with gomobile and react native

Tags: go, react-native, android-ndk, gomobile

```
package component

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)


type LastComponent struct {
    Name string
}

const fname = "componentfiles"


func Persist(comp string) string {
    lcomp := LastComponent{Name: comp}
    b, err := json.Marshal(lcomp)
    if err != nil {
        return "err-MARSHAL"
    }
    file, err := os.Create(fname)
    if err != nil {
        return "err-CREATE-FILE"
    }
    defer file.Close()
    _, err = file.Write(b)
    if err != nil {
        return "err-FILE-WRITE-PROB"
    }
    return ""
}

func Component() string {
    f, err := os.Open(fname)
    if err != nil {
        return "err-FILE-NOT-OPEN"
    }
    defer f.Close()
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    var v LastComponent
    json.Unmarshal(b, v)
    return v.Name
}


}
```

The code above works fine and so does the javascript side of code. I keep receiving `err-CREATE-FILE` inside my javascript. So `os.Create` and `os.Open` are not working as expected.

Although it is an internal storage, permissions are not required, but I also turned on the permissions in manifest file, but with no avail.

What could be the correct way to `Open` and `Create` files in android using gomobile when using along side React Native?

**Update:**

In `adb logcat`, I keep getting this all over the place

`E/Vold    (  276): Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.gotest/cache/`

Comment: What is the err from os.Create?  Have you tried saving using an absolute path - something like "/sdcard/myfile"?

Comment: are you able to open the file in Java/ObjC/Swift?

Answer (score 0):

So you should have some success if you pass this in as a parameter - something like the following is working for me:

go:

```
func Component(folderPath string) string {
    f, err := os.Open(path.Join(folderPath, fname)) 
    ...
```

Java:

```
Component.Component(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath())
```

Alternatively, you could use something like `getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`.  They key is that you need to get somewhere storagewise that is writable by your process/user.